# Error creating bean with name 'projectingArgumentResolverBeanPostProcessor' on Heroku Server

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, heroku, mybatis

**Environment**

Java : 11

Spring Boot : 2.4.0

MyBatis:2.1.3

redis:2.4.0

I try to use redis.

It works successful in a development environment.

but when I deployed it in the Heroku Server, It fails to start.

```xml
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- パスワードハッシュ化 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- orika-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ma.glasnost.orika</groupId>
            <artifactId>orika-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Java Mail API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- postgres -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- flyway -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Thyemeleaf拡張（セキュリティ） -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- webjars-locator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
            <version>0.40</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- marked -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>marked</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- highlightjs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>highlightjs</artifactId>
            <version>9.15.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- vue -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>vue</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- element ui -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>element-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- vue-chartjs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>github-com-apertureless-vue-chartjs</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- chartjs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>chartjs</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- bootstrap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jquery -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- exclude junit 4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.terasoluna.gfw</groupId>
            <artifactId>terasoluna-gfw-jodatime</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- junit 5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>5.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- NoSQL Redis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

```java
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean;
import org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.MybatisProperties;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.TransactionManagementConfigurer;

import jp.co.code_reminder.app.question.QuestionReviewCategoryForm;
import jp.co.code_reminder.domain.model.question.ReviewHistory;
import lombok.val;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SqlConfig implements TransactionManagementConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(this.dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean(final MybatisProperties mybatisProperties) {
        val sqlSessionFactoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        val resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        sqlSessionFactoryBean.setConfigLocation(resolver.getResource(mybatisProperties.getConfigLocation()));
        sqlSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        return sqlSessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean(name = "redisQrcTemplate")
    public RedisTemplate<String, QuestionReviewCategoryForm> redisQrcTemplate() {
        val redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, QuestionReviewCategoryForm>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(this.redisConnectionFactory);
        return redisTemplate;
    }

    @Bean(name = "redisReviewHistoryTemplate")
    public RedisTemplate<String, ReviewHistory> redisReviewHistoryTemplate() {
        val redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, ReviewHistory>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(this.redisConnectionFactory);
        return redisTemplate;
    }

     @Override
     public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
         return transactionManager();
     }

}
```

```
#Only written dataSource and redis configuration.


#DataSource
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url = ${DATABASE_JDBC_URL}
spring.datasource.username = ${DATABASE_USER}
spring.datasource.password = ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}

#redis
spring.session.store-type=redis
spring.redis.url=${REDIS_URL}
spring.redis.host=${REDIS_HOST}
spring.redis.user=${REDIS_USER}
spring.redis.password=${REDIS_PASSWORD}
spring.redis.port=${REDIS_PORT}
spring.redis.ssl=true
spring.redis.database=0
spring.redis.pool.max-active=8
spring.redis.pool.max-wait=-1
spring.redis.pool.max-idle=8
spring.redis.pool.min-idle=0
spring.redis.timeout=0
```

Error message as below.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
: at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
: at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
: at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
: at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
: at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:459)
: at webapp.runner.launch.Main.main(Main.java:289)
: Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
: at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
: at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
: at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
: ... 8 more
: Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
: at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
: at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
: at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
: at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
: at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
: at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
: at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
: at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
: ... 8 more
: Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
: at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
: at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
: at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
: ... 16 more
: Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
: at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
: at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
: at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
: at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
: at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
: at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
: at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
: at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
: ... 16 more
: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'projectingArgumentResolverBeanPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/web/config/ProjectingArgumentResolverRegistrar.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'transactionAdvisor' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor]: Factory method 'transactionInterceptor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method 'io.reactivex.Flowable io.reactivex.Flowable.fromPublisher(org.reactivestreams.Publisher)' the class loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @340da44c of the current class, org/springframework/core/ReactiveAdapterRegistry$RxJava2Registrar, and the class loader 'app' for the method's defining class, io/reactivex/Flowable, have different Class objects for the type org/reactivestreams/Publisher used in the signature (org.springframework.core.ReactiveAdapterRegistry$RxJava2Registrar is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @340da44c, parent loader 'app'; io.reactivex.Flowable is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:526)
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213)
: at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:244)
: at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:767)
: at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:572)
: at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144)
: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:751)
: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:410)
: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326)
: at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:173)
: at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:153)
: at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:95)
: at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174)
: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5135)
: at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
: ... 22 more
: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'transactionAdvisor' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor]: Factory method 'transactionInterceptor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method 'io.reactivex.Flowable io.reactivex.Flowable.fromPublisher(org.reactivestreams.Publisher)' the class loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @340da44c of the current class, org/springframework/core/ReactiveAdapterRegistry$RxJava2Registrar, and the class loader 'app' for the method's defining class, io/reactivex/Flowable, have different Class objects for the type org/reactivestreams/Publisher used in the signature (org.springframework.core.ReactiveAdapterRegistry$RxJava2Registrar is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @340da44c, parent loader 'app'; io.reactivex.Flowable is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798)
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:539)
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1179)
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571)
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531)
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213)
: at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:91)
: at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:111)
: at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:92)
: at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
: at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:251)
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1144)
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
: ... 40 more
: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor]: Factory method 'transactionInterceptor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method 'io.reactivex.Flowable io.reactivex.Flowable.fromPublisher(org.reactivestreams.Publisher)' the class loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @340da44c of the current class, org/springframework/core/ReactiveAdapterRegistry$RxJava2Registrar, and the class loader 'app' for the method's defining class, io/reactivex/Flowable, have different Class objects for the type org/reactivestreams/Publisher used in the signature (org.springframework.core.ReactiveAdapterRegistry$RxJava2Registrar is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @340da44c, parent loader 'app'; io.reactivex.Flowable is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656)
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636)
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1179)
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571)
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531)
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1367)
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
: ... 57 more
: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor]: Factory method 'transactionInterceptor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method 'io.reactivex.Flowable io.reactivex.Flowable.fromPublisher(org.reactivestreams.Publisher)' the class loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @340da44c of the current class, org/springframework/core/ReactiveAdapterRegistry$RxJava2Registrar, and the class loader 'app' for the method's defining class, io/reactivex/Flowable, have different Class objects for the type org/reactivestreams/Publisher used in the signature (org.springframework.core.ReactiveAdapterRegistry$RxJava2Registrar is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @340da44c, parent loader 'app'; io.reactivex.Flowable is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651)
: ... 71 more
: Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method 'io.reactivex.Flowable io.reactivex.Flowable.fromPublisher(org.reactivestreams.Publisher)' the class loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @340da44c of the current class, org/springframework/core/ReactiveAdapterRegistry$RxJava2Registrar, and the class loader 'app' for the method's defining class, io/reactivex/Flowable, have different Class objects for the type org/reactivestreams/Publisher used in the signature (org.springframework.core.ReactiveAdapterRegistry$RxJava2Registrar is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @340da44c, parent loader 'app'; io.reactivex.Flowable is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
: at org.springframework.core.ReactiveAdapterRegistry$RxJava2Registrar.registerAdapters(ReactiveAdapterRegistry.java:260)
: at org.springframework.core.ReactiveAdapterRegistry.<init>(ReactiveAdapterRegistry.java:91)
: at org.springframework.core.ReactiveAdapterRegistry.getSharedInstance(ReactiveAdapterRegistry.java:195)
: at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.<init>(TransactionAspectSupport.java:185)
: at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.<init>(TransactionInterceptor.java:63)
: at org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.transactionInterceptor(ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.java:65)
: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
: at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
: ... 72 more
```

I defined transactionInterceptor in SqlConfig.java.

but It's not change.

Checklist：

・Is redis defined way right?

・Is @EnableTransactionManagement defined way right?

→I hadn't defined @EnableTransactionManagement that until now.

but I can use @Transactional annotation.

I look forward to your answer.

Thank you.

Comment: Error message is below where?

Comment: I don't see the error message.

Comment: I added error message.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Having a similiar problem here.